# How to let developer get a look on pull-requests

Tags: github

I created a pull-request on GitHub repository whose last activity is half a year ago. But I am not sure whether this patch would be reviewed by developer. I do want this patch be applied to the repository.

I thought some way to notify the patch to the developer, but I am wondering which of these is the most effective way.

- tweet
- GitHub comment
- mail

Could you tell me the effective way to notify patch to developer?

Comment: I recently got a PR merged that was close to 3 years old … sometimes all it needs is a bit of time. While months or years are generally unreasonable, giving the maintainers a couple of weeks should be OK – no need to annoy them with extra notifications in addition to the original notification they got about the PR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A @ping on the PR itself seems the most "polite" to me. Alternatively, GitHub recently introduced a [reviewers feature](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-request-reviews/), so adding the relative developer there may also be useful.

If neither generate any response, I'd go for a private **polite** email. Using a tweet seems to me like publicly declaring that someone isn't properly maintaining their open-source project. I very much doubt that would get you the response you want.

Comment: FYI You can't ask for a review on GitHub if you don't have write access to the repository.

Answer (score 5):

The most effective way is usually to ping on the PR itself. Beside this, you could try a direct email.

Beside this you can maintain your own fork alright. That's the strength of FOSS after all!